# priority Connection License

Tags: vb.net, priority-web-sdk

so in the last version of priority rest-api they added something called "Application License" and they say you need to send in the header:  X-App-Id , X-App-Key. so i tried to put this in the header but this is not working really. The way i know just this park is not working caues this is a part of an app that was working fine but i need to update the app so this will work.
this is in vb tring to add the header in a mannaner that will work.

```
    'geeting info
    myParameters &= "url=" & Trim(Config.URL)
    myParameters &= "&tabulaini=" & Trim(Config.TabulaINI)
    myParameters &= "&language=" & Trim(Config.Language)
    myParameters &= "&company=" & Trim(TheCompany)
    myParameters &= "&username=" & Trim(Config.UserName)
    myParameters &= "&password=" & Trim(Config.Password)
    myParameters &= "&form=" & Trim(TheForm)
    myParameters &= "&doc=" & Trim(TheDoc)
    myParameters &= "&folder=" & Replace(Replace(Trim(Config.InFolder), "\", "/"), " ", "%20")
    myParameters &= "&file=" & Replace(Trim(NetFile), " ", "%20")

    'web request to the api
    Dim s As HttpWebRequest
    Dim enc As UTF8Encoding
    Dim postdata As String
    Dim postdatabytes As Byte()
    s = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:9876")
    'add the connection information the header
    s.Headers.Add("X-App-Id", "id")
    s.Headers.Add("X-App-Key", "CODE")
```

Answer (score 1):

the appID and appKey should be part of your parameters in the configuration object.

Here's a link to the appropriate section of the [Web-SDK] (https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/global/#login).